# Password encrypting method

Tags: encryption, methods

I was looking for password encrypting method that uses 140 symbols encrypts.

Like the one i have right here

```
"1f06b3b57542c78b08d9b2c8cd14a44ff6de52eefa60284af778c2d02c7f35e8cb28b972a8a597ed949da8538f2f494cc5813bb500b595dab3e8575d01284e983d525a70eb61"
```

so can anyone point me into the right direction?

Or at least give some info about that kind of method (140symbols) .

Comment: you can google bcrypt, which seems to be gaining adherents/apologists recently.

Comment: All of these are hex digits (0..f), so it's simply a sequence of 70 bytes. The number of ways to encrypt a password into a 70-byte sequence is near infinity.

Comment: If you could at least give a password+hash pair there would be a higher chance to figure out the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It's not encryption, it's hashing. Most likely, the algorithm works roughly as follows:

1) Generate a 6-byte salt.

2) Generate the SHA-512 hash of the password and salt.

3) Output the 6-byte salt followed by the 64-byte hash as a 140 character hex string.

Comment: how can i see what is in that hash afterwards?

Comment: @Exc you can't see what is in it and you don't need to. Simply hash a provided password and check if it matches the previously hashed password.

Comment: @Exc The hash is most likely the first 12 characters of the string. In your example, the hash was probably 1f06b3b57542.